# Old C compiler chokes on #ifndef #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to port some relatively modern C code to an older compiler.

This compiler ([DICE](http://legacy.obviously.com/dice/)), it seems, chokes on the first header file and the first occurrence of this idiom:

```
#ifndef SOMETHING
#define SOMETHING

...  

#endif /* SOMETHING */
```

it dies on the second line in the header with:
`DCPP: "../../code/someheader.h" L:2 C:0 Error:39 Syntax Error`

Changing to `#define SOMETHING 1` made no difference.

So I have really two questions, am I using DICE with the wrong option or something, or ***did C programmers use some other idiom equal to ifndef-define back in the old days?***

References:

- [DICE Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICE_%28compiler%29)
- [Original source code](http://legacy.obviously.com/dice/), runs on Unix
- Slightly updated [Amiga version](http://aminet.net/package/dev/c/dice-3.16)
- The author of DICE, Matt Dillon, went on to produce [DragonFlyBSD](http://www.dragonflybsd.org/)

Comment: If it's [this DICE compiler](http://www.obviously.com/amiga/) then that certainly used to work with typical include guards.

Comment: My first edition (21st printing) K&R describes #ifndef on page 208, so it's been around for a while.

Comment: Ooh, that question brings back memories! I even paid for the shareware version. :) Besides that, it should work, otherwise all system headers would fail as well.

Comment: You don't have any spaces before or after the `#` in the actual source file? Don't remember if it was sensitive to that or not.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is something else. Maybe the source files use a different line terminator than the compiler supports?

Comment: Extra comment: looking at the source (if it is the DICE I thought) then whitespaces seems to only include carriage returns. So it might be barfing on linefeeds if you have those in your line endings.

Comment: @interjay, katching!  You are correct. Please write an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @tinman, or you.  First come, first served. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it is [this C compiler](http://www.obviously.com/amiga/) then by looking at the [sources](http://www.obviously.com/dice/) (src\dcpp\cpp.c) you can see that newlines only include the carriage return character and not the linefeed character.

If you have a line ending with CRLF then when the compiler strips the whitespace at the start of the line, it does not strip the linefeed before the `#` which is a syntax error, since preprocessor directives starting with `#` must be the first non-whitespace character in the line.

Comment: Heh, you beat me by a second :) I'll delete my answer, enjoy the rep.

Comment: @interjay: Thanks, very sporting of you :)

Comment: Thank you all, good to see so many C savvy and Amiga tainted people. :-)

Comment: I don't care whether you need the rep, but the effort and a perfect answer are a definite +1.

Comment: By the way the analysis of the error is top notch, I see now.

Answer (score 3):

```
#if SOMETHING
#else




#endif
```

might just work everywhere

Comment: Thank you!  That was not it but might help another compiler.